# Magento 2 - product final price issue

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules

If I try to print `price` and `final_price` from `$_product` in category page template (`product/list.phtml`), they have the same value despite the product is affected by a catalog rule.
Why?

How can I get the discounted price in there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your price indexes (actually all your indexes) are up to date.
The prices in the product list don't come directly from the product entity. They come from the table `catalog_product_index_price` where the indexed prices are kept.
If you have a discount rule that you just created but you did not rebuild the indexes you won't see the proper prices in the list.
This does not apply to the product view page because here the prices come from the product entity directly.

Comment: Also in `catalog_product_index_price` they are the same. You're right.
I've tried to update all my indexes (`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`) but nothing's changed.

Comment: did you clear the cache? Do you have varnish in front of your web server and maybe that is cached.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache. But also in the table the `final_price` didn't changed.
I'm not using varnish.. I'm developing in a local environment.

Comment: And then, if I try to get product entity in my block (child of `ListProduct` in `list.phtml`) in this way: `$this->_productRepository->getById($id);` I don't found `final_price` attribute..